# Align text on a button in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a tiny button in IE using css, but the title is not vertically centered ... how do I do that?

"vertical-align: middle;" has no effect :(

Here's my css...

```
.tinyButton
{
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #d1d1d1) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #d1d1d1 100% );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5');
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-top-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-top-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    color: #777777;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

Thanks!!
Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try already:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

---

edit:
height of button needed to be adjusted to fit text properly

Comment: Yeah - this has no effect. :(

Comment: which IE do you test it in pls?

Comment: without vertical-align, i've changed your code to height: 16px; and in IE 9 text is perfectly in the middle of the button..

Comment: Sorry my bad - how embarrassing ... I had linked another CSS file which had "lineheight: 20px" ... I feel stupid. But thank you so much for your effort - knowing that it worked in your browser, made me look for the problem in other files. Thanks! Mojo

Answer (score 4):

Try to set a smaller line-height for example:

```
line-height: 5px
```

and if it's for IE7 only you can do it like this:

```
*line-height: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Adjusted with padding
   padding: 3px 13px 5px;
2. removed attribute height
3. Added attribute
   float:left;

CSS

```
    .tinyButton {
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, 
        color-stop(0.05,#ffffff),  color-stop(1, #d1d1d1) );
        background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #d1d1d1 100% );
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',
        endColorstr='#e5e5e5');
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-top-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-top-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        color: #777777;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 8px;
        padding: 3px 13px 5px;
        float:left;
    }
```